# Pass parameter from StackNavigator to TabNavigator then to StackNavigator inside the TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a Splash Screen implemented using StackNavigator. From it I navigate to TabNavigator in which each Tabs contains a StackNavigator. How can i pass a param from the Splash screen to Components in the StackNavigators of TabNavigator

**Splash**

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
              {
                type: 'Navigation/INIT',
                routeName: 'TabScreen',
                params: {
                  userLocation
                }
              }
            ]
          })
          this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

**TabNavigator**

```
const InformationStack = StackNavigator({
  Information: { screen: Information },
});

const TabScreen = TabNavigator(
  {
    Information: { screen: InformationStack }
  },
```

I cannot access the params inside Information. Someone please help

```
params: { userLocation }
```

Comment: Solved it by changing TabScreen to Class
class TabScreen extends React.Component {
  router = TabScreen = TabNavigator(
    {     
      Information: { screen: InformationStack }
    },
    
  )

  render() {
    return <TabScreen screenProps={{ params: this.props.navigation.state.params }} />
  }
}